# Errors installing Drywall

Tags: git, authentication, github, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to install drywall and I am getting many errors

```
C:\Users\zach\Desktop\Node.js\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_con      fig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\.      .\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYT       HON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\nod          e_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:116:14) 
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node          -gyp\lib\configure.js:71:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodej      s\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\zach\Desktop\Node.js\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\               node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zach\Desktop\Node.js\drywall\npm-debug.log
```

Should I be worried about any of these? If anyone knows of a guide on how to solve these errors (i have searched a lot and can't find one) please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the configure/install step for bcrypt is failing due to a missing dependency on python.

> gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can
>   set the PYT       HON env variable.

bcrypt0.8.5 has the following dependencies,

- NodeJs
- node-gyp
- Python 2.x
- OpenSSL

[-Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

Make sure all of bcrypts dependencies are installed and then try again.

Comment: THANK YOU! On the Drywall github page, I only saw info about 2 of these dependencies. This helps me out so much, i'll be sure to upvote this once i get the reputation!